# How do I colour bars in ggplot2 to indicate different categories?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm relatively new to R, and I'm trying to build a barplot in ggplot2. I want to color different bars to indicate which "Group" they belong to, but when I plot this I find that the order of the legend does not match the order of the "Diet Items" (on the x-axis). The legend is listed in the default alphabetical order.

What is the best way to make the order of the legend match the plot?

My data looks like this:

```
 str(Diet)  
'data.frame':   27 obs. of  4 variables:  
 $ Group     : Factor w/ 7 levels "algae","crustacean",..: 1 1 1 1 1 5 5 5 5 5 ...  
 $ Category  : Factor w/ 27 levels "algae","biofilm",..: 1 2 8 11 21 4 9 10 14 15 ...  
 $ studies_n : int  61 4 8 18 2 59 90 76 57 119 ...   
 $ studies_pc: num  38.4 2.5 5 11.3 1.3 37.1 56.6 47.8 35.8 74.8 ... 

 head(Diet)  
   Group      Category studies_n studies_pc  
1  algae         algae        61       38.4  
2  algae       biofilm         4        2.5  
3  algae       diatoms         8        5.0  
4  algae       fil alg        18       11.3  
5  algae phytoplankton         2        1.3  
6 insect    Coleoptera        59       37.1
```

and the plot I have built looks like this:

[plot of diet categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BD8Od.png)

Here is my code:

```
abPalette <- c("#009E73","#E69F00","#000000","#999999",  "#56B4E9",  "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7")

barplot3 <- qplot(xlab="Diet Items", ylab="Number of studies", x=Diet$Category, y=Diet$studies_n, fill=Diet$Group, geom="bar", stat="identity") + coord_flip() + labs(fill="Diet Group") +scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(Diet$Category)) + scale_fill_manual(values=abPalette)

barplot3
```

I have been researching this for several days and tried several methods, and I'm still willing to scrap it all for new code if there is an easier way to do it!

Adding dput:

```
dput(Diet)
structure(list(Group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("algae", "crustacean", "detritus", 
"fish", "insect", "mollusc", "other"), class = "factor"), Category = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 8L, 11L, 21L, 4L, 9L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 19L, 22L, 
25L, 3L, 13L, 18L, 12L, 5L, 6L, 27L, 7L, 24L, 20L, 23L, 26L), .Label = c("algae", 
"biofilm", "Bivalvia", "Coleoptera", "Crustacea", "Decapoda", 
"detritus", "diatoms", "Diptera", "Ephemeroptera", "fil alg", 
"fish", "Gastropoda", "Hemiptera", "insects", "Lepidoptera", 
"Megaloptera", "Mollusca", "Odonata", "other", "phytoplankton", 
"Plecoptera", "terr invert", "terr veg", "Trichoptera", "vertebrate", 
"zooplankton"), class = "factor"), studies_n = c(61L, 4L, 8L, 
18L, 2L, 59L, 90L, 76L, 57L, 119L, 41L, 13L, 53L, 49L, 80L, 7L, 
50L, 12L, 114L, 13L, 55L, 90L, 116L, 112L, 25L, 56L, 2L), studies_pc = c(38.4, 
2.5, 5, 11.3, 1.3, 37.1, 56.6, 47.8, 35.8, 74.8, 25.8, 8.2, 33.3, 
30.8, 50.3, 4.4, 31.4, 7.5, 71.7, 8.2, 34.6, 56.6, 73, 70.4, 
15.7, 35.2, 1.3)), .Names = c("Group", "Category", "studies_n", 
"studies_pc"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -27L))
```

Comment: Can you put a `dput` of your data in your question?

Comment: Please use the proper formatting for your code!

Comment: Is this what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest solution is to just reorder the `Diet` data.frame upfront:

```
Diet <- Diet[order(Diet$Group), ]

ggplot(Diet, aes(x = Category, y = studies_n, fill = Group)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(Diet$Category))
```

[image: Plot01]

Alternatively, you could set the levels of the `Diet$Group` to be in the order as they are stated in the given data.frame:

```
Diet$Group <- factor(Diet$Group, levels = unique(Diet$Group))

ggplot(Diet, aes(x = Category, y = studies_n, fill = Group)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(Diet$Category))
```

[image: Plot02]

Comment: You are my hero! Such an easy solution when you know how. :)